# Microsoft Access (2010) was unable to export data using export query for xml

Tags: xml

Hi I am trying to use ExportXML Method in MS Access for exporting a query with a user input using forms.

**I get the error:
Run - time error '31532'
Microsoft Access was unable to export the data**

This is the code that I used.

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, DataSource:="eparcelorder", _
DataTarget:="C:\XML\" + tmpWorkOrderNo.Caption + ".xml", _
WhereCondition:="dbo_eParcel.workorderno = '" & Forms!frmMainForm![tmpWorkOrderNo].   [Caption] & "'"
End Sub
```

Is there any limitations in MS Access 2010 that prevents exporting data when it asks user input or using criteria?

Thank you in advance for your help! I've been working on this for a week and it is a very simple function

Answer (score 1):

I use the attached to produce a 3 million line nested xml in about five minutes.

There are two key items,

1) a simple piece of VB,

Public Function Export_ListingData()

```
Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_address"
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_buildingDetails"
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessDetails"
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtras"
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccounts"
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccom"
objOtherTbls.Add "ro_businessExtrasAccom2"

Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
            DataSource:="ro_business", _
            DataTarget:="C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Conversions\ListData.xml", _
            AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls
```

Exit_Here:
        MsgBox "Export_ListingData completed"
        Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Resume Exit_Here
End Function

2) Linking the tables in relationship manager using joins from primary to FOREIGN keys.

If there are no relationships the code will produce a sequential xml file, if there are
relationships between primary keys you will get a 31532 error and the data export will fail.

Kind Regards

Steve

Comment: Related: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/run-time-error-31532-using-export-query-to-xml/0c1de8d9-01cc-452b-9fef-c16453b3d16c?auth=1